# MySQL UNION SELECT until found?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, union

Let's say I have table with column 'URL' whrere I store urls like this

- one/two
- one/two/three
- alpha/omega

And I want to get data from database for specific url and if it is not found I remove the last part of url and search again:

Example:

I have url like one/two/three/four/five.

I do search for "one/two/three/four/five"

if not found search again for "one/two/three/four"

if not found search again for "one/two/three"

if not found search again for "one/two"

I would like to have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE url=one/two/three/four/five

UNION

SELECT * FROM db WHERE url=one/two/three/four/five

UNION

SELECT * FROM db WHERE url=one/two/three/four

UNION

SELECT * FROM db WHERE url=one/two/three

UNION

SELECT * FROM db WHERE url=one/two

UNION

SELECT * FROM db WHERE url=one
```

but I want to stop searching if the row is found.

Is this possible or do I have to do it with separated queries.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thing that this is the most **elegant** approach to your question. This statement is independent depth path and you don't need to split constant url in subsequent selects:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   db 
WHERE 
   concat( 'one/two/three/four/five' , '/') like concat( url , '/%')
ORDER BY
   LENGTH (url) desc
LIMIT 1
```

I have tested this query in MySQL, also [you can check it! (in MSSQL syntax)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58817)

Comment: I have now tested Your and _newtover_'s way with 5000 loops and I must say your way is in most cases much faster (5.34 to 6.84 times faster). Only if there is only one level url (e.g. "one"), the _newtover_'s way is about twice as fast as yours, so I will use your way. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: I have run same test for the second way and it is about 10 to 15 % slower, so your original solution works best.

Comment: Ok, nice try. Please, forget comment, I delete it. Have a happy new year =)

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL` and add `LIMIT 1` at the end.

P.S. `UNION ALL` would not make much difference in this particular example, but it is useful to know the difference: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/

Comment: @posuk13, I would like you to point out what is wrong with the solution when you are minusing. UNION ALL allows MySQL optimizer to short circuit the execution when it has enought rows to output. If you do not need any help, why do you even ask here?

Comment: I was not minusing-it was somebody else. I gave you plus because your answer is for me the best. Simple and exactly what I was looking for. I want just one row because of MySQL optimalization. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @posuk13, I am sorry, I thought it was you because the minuses to both other aswers came right after your comment to lcarus.

Comment: I had to change my selection to _danihp_'s way because of tests results (see comments under his post). But anyway, thanks

Comment: @Posuk13, no problem. I like his solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let's say I have table with column 'URL' whrere I store urls like this

one/two

one/two/three

alpha/omega
```

Don't do that, it's a horrible design and the proof is the problem you are having running such a simple query; store each URl on a DIFFERENT ROW. Read up on Normalization.

Comment: Yes. That was the plan to store each uri in separate row

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regexp to search in a single query, but it'll get you all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE url REGEXP "^one((/two)|(/two/three)|(two/three/four)|(/two/three/four/five))?$"
```

so if you only want the results from the first `WHERE` you'll have to do multiple queries.
If you really want to have a single query and don't care about a little overhead in the search you could do

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE url REGEXP "^one((/two)|(/two/three)|(two/three/four)|(/two/three/four/five))?$" ORDER BY length(url) DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will get you the first possible result only, but the query inside will have to get all possible results first -> less efficient, but more compact.

I hope this helps!

Comment: the former query could have delivered wrong results, but I corrected it to not deliver relults like `/one/three` or simmilar